# Angular CLI: CSS does not load image from asset

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have this directory in my project. The application is working fine, and I remove any unrelated directory in below structure.

```
e2e
node_modules
src
 |--app
      |--app.component.css   <--Image is not loaded at all
      |--app.component.ts
      |--app.component.html  <--Html can load image correctly
 |--assets
      |--images
           |--play.png       <--What I want in css
.angular-cli.json
```

It is confirmed that I can load the image from HTML file by using this syntax:

`HTML file`

```
<img src="/assets/images/play.png" alt="">

<!-- This will load image from css -->
<div class="sample-image"></div>
```

`CSS file`

```
.sample-image {
  /* Not working at all*/
  /* Url I've tried: /assets, ../assets, ./assets, ../images */
  background-image: url(/assets/images/play.png);
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I can tell where the image should load since I put background-color to show where it should be.

I've checked the [Github page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4806) to see if it is related, but for me even in development using `ng serve` it seems to not working. I haven't tried to build it yet.

**UPDATE**: I'm sorry for depicting wrong directory structure, my eyes were focus on the src folder that I forgot app and assets is in src. I've updated it.

**UPDATE 2**: Here is an angular-cli json file. I've not tampered as I remembered when I create the project with `ng` command:

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: its `/assets/image/play.png`, you put `/assets/images/play.png` in your CSS the image url path is wrong compare to your folder tree.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I've updated the directory name. I confirmed the folder name is `images`

Comment: try using ./assets/image/play.png

Comment: I've done that but it gives compile error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/images/play.png' in 'C:\Sites Angular\radiant-ng\src\app'`. Removing the `.` will compile successfuly

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `angular-cli.json` configuration

```
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  ....
}
```

You are having **src as your root** folder, and your **assets** folder is inside the **app**. Move the assets folder inside src.

Update 1 : Based on new directory structure

Remove the / in front of the assets in your src URL

```
<img src="assets/images/play.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Sorry I've depicted a wrong directory structure. Please check the updated one

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything DOES working fine, except one silly mistake.

The image itself.

`play.png`
[image]

Should've check the image before I does anything else. Turn out the image is larger than the width I specified in the css, which in return shows the `transparent area` of the image.

Changing to other image helps me find this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the app.component.css, use the relative url of the image. For the given scenario, set css as follows:

```
.sample-image {
  background-image: url('../assets/images/play.png');
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

don't forget the quotes in url.